# Android how to stop my timer correctly display the hh:mm:ss they carry on counting after 60

Tags: android

I have created a timer using runnable and the run method in my android application. The problem i have encountered is that when the minutes or seconds reach 60, they should reset back to 00. After either the minutes or seconds reach 60, they carry on counting so for example:

when: hh:mm:ss are displayed as 00:00:59 and another second ticks by then format is now shown as 00:01:60 then 00:01:61 so how can i a prevent this issue from taking place.

Will i have to use a condition statement that says:

```
if(seconds > 59){

seconds = 0;

}
```

here is the code in question:

```
public void startCountingTimer() {

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        handler = new Handler();
        task = new Runnable() { 
            @Override
            public void run() {


                millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis);
                mins =  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis));
                secs = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis));      

                timeString = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hours, mins, secs);
                timerTextView.setText(timeString);
                handler.postDelayed(task, 1000); 

            }
        };
        task.run();
    }
```

Comment: When you say `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))` you are converting your milliseconds to minutes `millis / 60000` and then converting those minutes "to seconds" using a millisecond to seconds conversion, or `firstResult / 1000` which is probably not the behavior you were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would only keep track of the millis and then use division and modulus to find mins/hours:

```
int millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
int secs = millis / 1000 % 60; // seconds, 0 - 59
int mins = millis / 1000 / 60 % 60; // total seconds / 60, 0 - 59
int hours = millis / 1000 / 60 / 60; // total seconds / 3600, 0 - limitless
```

That way you can never pass 60 on seconds or minutes, but I'm assuming you don't care if hours goes over 24 or you would do the same thing.

Another option would be to change your:

```
secs = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis));
```

to:

```
secs = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis));
```

Notice the change from `- TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS` to `- TimeUnit.MINUTES`

Comment: Also, you could probably use your `TimeUnit`s but use modulus instead of subtracting?  Sorry, I've just never used `TimeUnit` before, so I did it the old fashion way.

Comment: ye i was going to it the old fashioned way as i do in C and such but i thought TimeUnit maybe the "correct" approach, guess there isnt a huge difference. +1 and answer selected, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by other responders, you have a mistake in your unit conversions.

In the interest of readable code, I suggest you separate the unit conversions from the calculations.  Even though the code below is verbose, I like it because I can look at it and have confidence that the calculations are correct:

```
    millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    totalHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis);
    totalMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis);
    totalSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis);

    totalHoursAsMinutes = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(totalHours);
    totalMinutesAsSeconds = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(totalMinutes);

    hours = totalHours;   
    mins = totalMins - totalHoursAsMinutes; 
    secs = totalSeconds - totalMinutesAsSeconds;
```

If you find this is too verbose, then write it out in the verbose form first to be sure you have it right, then substitute variables to "collapse" it the terse form:

```
    hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis);
    mins = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) 
        - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis));  
    secs = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) 
        - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis));
```

BTW: The verbose form is more "efficient" for what it's worth.